# Wait until a View is loaded and then put loaded data in it

Tags: android

I have this small problem. My custom `View` takes to load from 100 ms to 1 s depending on how fast is the phone. The view is in `Fragment` but I'm loading data in the `MainActivity`. Sometimes the data is loaded faster than the `View` in `Fragment` which happens to be blank since the data is not present in the View.

How can I delay data input into the `View`?

Comment: add a callback to be fired once view finished loading.

Comment: see fargment lifecycle: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: You can assign data to your custom view in Fragment's `onViewCreated()`

Comment: @VladMatvienko I guess this is the answer for me

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that. Personally I would like to suggest you to use `ProgressFragment` for these purpose. [Here's a nice library](https://github.com/johnkil/Android-ProgressFragment) to show a default progress animation when the data is still being loaded.

The implementation of the library is quite simple.

Add this in your `gradle` dependancies.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.johnkil.android-progressfragment:progressfragment:1.4.+'
}
```

Now your `Fragment` should extend the `ProgressFragment`

```
public class MyProgressFragment extends ProgressFragment {
    // your code of fragment
}
```

Setup content view in `onActivityCreate()` method.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Setup content view
    setContentView(R.layout.content);
}
```

Display of indeterminate progress indicator by calling in `onActivityCreated`

```
setContentShown(false);
```

When the data is available, jut make sure to display the associated `View` in the right place.

```
if (this.isAdded()) setContentShown(true);
```

One thing you need to remember while implementing this library that you need to have a parent layout for the `View` you want to show/hide which layout id will be `android:id="@+id/content_container"`

As I said earlier, there are some other ways too. If you go through the `Fragment` [lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), you'll definitely find a way to populate your data when the `View` is available. Just populating your data inside `onActivityCreated` should help you in this case too.